# Job Opportunity and difficulty (or not) for me to learn to use msaccess and surveygizmo/alchemer

Tags: database-design, query, ms-access, relational-theory

First, if my question fits better elsewhere, please advise.

My question is: Based on your experience with relational databases like MSaccess and perhaps survey tools like Alchemer (formerly Survey Gizmo), can you help me get a better idea of the difficulty/ease for me, given my background, to quickly learn these technical tools in order to contribute well to the following role?

Background: I am considering applying for a job that is more pure research-oriented than what I have been doing lately. The position is in public health, at an agency that evaluates and provides information on public health programs and outcomes. I have a research-focused M.A. degree in experimental psychology which is relevant to the position, plus another relevant Master's degree. I also have done relevant types of research and used various tools in service of that research. This is a research role, as an associate researcher, working with a principle investigator and other associate researchers.

What I have not done that this role includes: I have not used MSaccess, nor survey gizmo. (But I am a very good researcher and am plenty resourceful :).)

What I have done: Intermediate user of SPSS, Beginning/Intermediate use of Structural Equation Modeling software (years ago), Advanced business and research user of Excel (can add in simple VBA code if needed, can make tables, graphs, and solve more challenging data orientation and linking problems). Have used FileMaker Pro, Zoho (for recruiting and applicant tracking). I have worked for large tech companies like Intel for years. Completely proficient with everyday Office software (PowerPoint, Word, Google Surveys/Forms/Docs/other tools). I also have the subject-matter knowledge, writing ability, project management ability etc. for the role.

What the role requires, functionally (that I would need to learn):

1. Develop tables, forms, queries and reports consisting of study tracking and recruitment data.
2. Be able to refine and manage the above as needed.
3. Management, programming and testing of remotely-administered survey gizmo/Alchemer surveys
4. Prepare study methods/procedures documentation and data codebooks (this seems pretty straight-forward and I would assume there would be examples from this or other projects, plus standards for doing so in the field such as government repositories of such public health information).

There are lots of other activities required that would be no problem for me. The above are the ones I would need to learn.

I'm mainly concerned about how hard it would be to adequately learn enough to do 1, 2, and 3 above competently enough to contribute well in this kind of collaborative research atmosphere.

The role is currently remote.

I appreciate any thoughts you may have based on above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, unfortunately this kind of question is not fitting (mostly because it's an opinionated question) for **DBA.StackExchange** so it'll likely be closed. But to hopefully offer up some helpful advice anyway, you should start looking into those technologies now and try reaching yourself to get an idea of how difficult your future in that position might be.

**MS Access** as a database essentially uses a basic version of **SQL** which is where I'd recommend focussing first. You can follow [this SQL tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) by W3Schools and see how difficult it feels to learn. Learning this skill now is good because it's usable in multiple roles (not just one that employs **MS Access**). W3Schools also has a page on [**MS Access** functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_msaccess.asp) which is probably worth a read over.

Once you feel comfortable with **SQL** from the above then you should look into **MS Access** specifically which you can follow [this in-depth tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/index.htm) on.

If you feel comfortable with both **SQL** and **MS Access** after the above you'll likely be fine in this job role. **Gizmo/Alchemer surveys** are too specific and not widely used so you won't find much input on **StackExchange** about them, but they're likely a lot simpler to learn than the previous two objectives of learning **SQL** and **MS Access**. So if you can pick up those two skills comfortably, you probably won't have issues learning **Gizmo/Alchemer** on the job as well.

Comment: Thank you. I can see your point RE appropriateness of post. I had forgotten from my limited use of stacks. Still, great info and links and I am grateful you took the time to share them. I've copied them to save them as I assume this will get deleted, rightfully, per policy.

Comment: @SC_TimeSavor Actually you're in luck, they stay even though the question is closed, but doesn't hurt to save for your references. No worries about appropriateness either, having your question closed isn't anything personal, just to keep the forum tidy and relevant. Best of luck, and if you have any specific questions about MS Access or SQL then those will be appropriate for here. :)